# What should I do if the pressure is too high in a home water pressure increasing system?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

Hi I have two well x trols and a large water storage tank. This system was put in before I bought the house 2 years ago and it it supposed to increase the water pressure in the home. The problem is the ball cock valve broke and the large water tank started overflowing. Then I noticed the pressure gauge on the water pump showing over 100 PSI. is the water from the mains coming in at too high a pressure? What do I do?

I am including some pictures to show the situation. I dont know the flow of water. I do see a pressure valve between the storage tank and the pressure pump.

[image: connections]

[image: pump2]
[image: pump 3]
[image: pump 4]
[image: pump 5]

Comment: Hard to be sure. For one thing I can tell you that putting PVC pipe out in the sunshine will make it brittle - it needs to be protected from the sun, by at least a layer of paint.

Comment: Can anyone explain the direction of water flow? I thought it came from the mains into the blue tanks and the into the storage tank but that doesnt make sense.  am now thinking it comes into the tank and then when the level drops below a certain level in the house tank, the motor starts and pumps water from the storage tank (bottom pipe) into the wellxtrols and thereby to the house. Is that right??

Comment: I can only guess from what I can see here - much of which seriously makes me wonder about why this was set up this way, "really." Because it appears to me that the water feed is probably from the valve in the center right of the top picture, and the first thing it hits is a pressure regulator (which would reduce it's pressure) then it seems to go up to fill the green tank, but there's a black hose tee-ed off the pipe up the side of the green tank. The pump input is to the center, so off the bottom of the green tank, and the pump output is to the side, off to the galvanized pipes to the blue

Answer (score 1):

I think my first step in sorting this out would be to positively identify the feed from the supply main, shut it off at the main, cut this whole business out at least temporarily, and connect the house to the main without all this "stuff."

If, as appears to be the case, the pressure from the main is being reduced before it's increased, something is just plain odd, and it costs a lot of electricity to be that odd, not to mention the complexity. Put a pressure gauge on it and see what you actually have for pressure before concerning yourself too much with this mess.

An alternate possibility is that this is supposed to isolate the house from times when the supply of water is not there at all - in which case it's a poor job of designing a system for that purpose, IMHO. Does your water utility fail to provide water on a regular basis?